# Getting a request parameter in a servlet from html form set with EL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el

I have a JSP with the following EL/html tags:

```
    <c:forEach var="key" items="${resource.stringPropertyNames()}">
    <tr>
        <td>${key}</td>
        <td><input type = "text" name = "${key}" value = "${resource.get(key)}"></td>                           
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

When my jsp is rendered, the first `<td>` tag shows the evaluated value of ${key}. In the `<input>` tag however, the ${key} is not evaluated correctly. When I try to retrieve the input as request parameters from my servlet (`request.getParameter(StringKey)`), I get the literal `$key` without the braces. When I do `request.getParameter("$key")`, I get multiple values for the Strings that `${resource.get(key)}` evaluate to in the EL.

What is going on?

**EDIT**

Controller method (using spring) code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = URI_PATH + "{fileName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getProperties(@PathVariable String fileName, ModelMap modelMap) {
        Properties resource = ..//get properties file
        modelMap.addAttribute("resource", resource);
        return "configuration" // maps to my jsp;
    }
```

Comment: I can answer your question clearer if you go to the source code of the page (view page source) and paste that in your question.

Comment: A `<td>` tag evaluates to: `<td><input type = "text" name = "$key" value = "English"></td>`. So the value EL gets the right value, but the name doesn't.

Comment: If you set the attribute in your servlet you do not need to call it with the .

Comment: `resource` which is a Properties object is the only object used in request.setAttribute("resource", resource). I use the stringPropertyNames() to get a set of Strings and get(key) to get a particular value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If resource is a Map, which is set using `request.setAttribute("resource", resource)`

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${resource}">
<tr>
    <td>${entry.key}</td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "${entry.key}" value = "${entry.value}"></td>                           
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: This worked and is something I didn't know could be done in EL, but it doesn't explain why mine didn't.