# check if request attribute is set with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

Is it possible to check if a attribute is present in a request object?
I have certain error cases where a error message has to be delivered to the client side:

Servlet Code:

```
request.setAttribute("error", "The following term was not found in the index: " + terms);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("graph.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

I tried it like this, but I don't get an alert window at all...

JSP Code:

```
<script>
   var test = "${error}";
   if(test != null)
       alert(test);
</script>
```

Comment: Where did you get `${error}` syntax from? You're going to need to show more of your Javascript...

Comment: error in syntax; jQuery works as a function; maybe it was $(error) or something like that?

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean then no.  The request object only exists on the server.  By the time your page is rendered, sent to the browser, and scripts run, there's no such thing as a request object.

Comment: Are you expecting `${error}` to evaluate because it's EL?

Comment: Is your first code snippet on the server? Is it part of an AJAX call? If it sends that back to the client, the error will be in something like `data.error`, where `data` is the parameter to the AJAX callback function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a request parameter in a servlet from html form set with EL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481155/getting-a-request-parameter-in-a-servlet-from-html-form-set-with-el)

Comment: I used this: var xyz = "${xyz}"; all the time on my jsp pages, to get attributes which have been set in a servlet with request.setAttribute("xyz", "whatever"); .. and that works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Ian, yes. That worked in other cases as well. Not sure why it won't work now

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, you have a JSP app outputting this JavaScript. In other words your JSP page sets the variable error to a string value.  This is then used to generate JavaScript which you want to alert the contents of the error variable.

Your JS code is generally correct.  A couple things stand out to me:

1) add a language attribute to the script tag (shown below)

```
<script language="javascript">
    var test = "${error}";
    if(test != null)
        alert(test);
</script>
```

2) check for errors in your browser

I tested the code you have here and it works for me when the error value is something akin to "hello world".  The test variable gets set to this.  A string is not equal to null (though an empty string is also not equal to null so your if statement's a bit useless).  This makes me think that perhaps the string you're outputting from ${error} may have a double quote in it.

Let's say your error is: The following term was not found in the index: "avocado".

Your generated JS would look like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var test = "The following term was not found in the index: "avocado"";
    if(test != null)
        alert(test);
</script>
```

Note the double quotes in the double quoted string.  This is a syntax error.

If you're using chrome open up the developer tools (View > Developer > Console).  Reload the page.  Do you see an error message reported?  If yes, what's the error?  If no, view your source and look at the generated JS and post it here for scrutiny.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. First of all, the error attribute will only be set by the servlet some times, but not all the times. Meaning that it sometimes will be empty. I want to figure out if that's the case. Second, the string terms will never have double or single quotation in it. So I wouldn't worry about that. Third, the JS code is inside a JSP Page. Where can I see it in the Developer Tools? I have the view called "Elements", where I can see the code, but there's no error message.

Comment: if I trigger the program with invalid input my source code looks like this: var test = "The following term was not found in the index: sdfsdfsdf";
if(test != null)
 alert(test);
</script> ... but there is no alert message showing. In the other case (valid input) there's an empty alert message and the code looks like this: var test = "";
if(test != null)
 alert(test); .. In this case the attribute was not set at all in the servlet

Comment: I have made a few assumptions here. I'm assuming you're requesting the JSP page via a web browser. Is that correct? If your web browser is chrome, you should be able to open Chrome's console  (View > Developer > Console) and see the error message reported, if there is one.

Comment: I also have to say I've not done a ton with JSP, but JSP's syntax should be something like <%= expression %> to output a variable into the html.  I think this mean that your JSP's code should look like var test = "<%= error %>", right?  Another question, why not put the logic in Java rather than JavaScript? IE: <% if(error){ %><script language="javascript">alert("<%= error %>");</script><% } %>.  Note that the existence of the error variable is left up to Java in the JSP.  Lastly, if you set error = "<%=error %>" in JS, no error message would be "" so your logic should be if(error != "")

Comment: @DougHughes: `var test = "${error}";` allows to get the request attribute "error". Is there a way to set a request attribute in a similar way in javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for empty but not for null in your case.
`if(test != "")`